# Apache Tomcat - Ubuntu Setup

Tags: java, apache, shell, tomcat, java-home

In order to get tomcat working on my ubuntu, i downloaded "apache-tomcat-8.5.4.tar.gz"-file

Next i decompressed it and moved it to an other location:

```
tar -xvzf apache-tomcat-8.5.4.tar.gz
sudo mkdir -p /opt/tomcat
sudo mv apache-tomcat-8.5.4 /opt/tomcat/
```

I also added some variables to system:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_102
export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.4
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

sourced it:

```
source .profile
```

When i run:

```
java -version
```

it correctly prints:

```
1.8.0_102 .. etc
```

But when i run:

```
sudo $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

it fails with message:

```
Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program
```

Anybody could refer to this issue?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: Can you run "which java" to make sure you're getting the java command from where you're expecting it?

Comment: outputs: "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_102/bin/java", it is the jdk which i downloaded and set in my variable JAVA_HOME, why?

Comment: I was just verifying.  I feel like the sudo is not picking up your environment - have you tried to run startup.sh as yourself? The directories "temp", "webapps", "logs", and "work" in /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.4 will need to be writable by you.

Comment: yes i also executed "./startup.sh" from directory: "/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.4/bin", but same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having this configuration inside your $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh:

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_102

CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.4

**Put it as the first two lines of the file so it can use it later on.**

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks u solver it!! but i still don't know why my approach does not work

Comment: because your tomcat user is not the same as the one you are loading your profile, so instead of making you see all the user stuff, by putting these lines you will make it work with all users at once

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are running **sudo** and the environment is not setup properly.

I would add the following exports to the **/etc/environment** file so that they are system wide.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_102 
export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.4 
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

Then edit the sudoers file with *sudo visudo* and add this to the file:

```
Defaults env_keep += "JAVA_HOME CATALINA_HOME"
```

That will allow you to run the *sudo* command and have the environment setup properly. I would not recommend modifying the **catalina.sh** script.